# ML with sklearn: KNeighborRegressor fit function stuck on a big DB

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nearest-neighbor

I've been working with sklearn tools for a while now, but I have this weird issue right now. I'm simply trying to build a KNN Regressor with sklearn, but the execution is taking forever, and when debugging it looks like the execution of the fit function is taking forever.
I should mention that the dataset is big (~25,000 records, with 10 features), but still - I'm waiting for an hour now and no results.

What could cause this?

The relevant piece of code:

```
 X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.25, random_state = 42)
regressor = neighbors.KNeighborsRegressor(n_neighbors = n, algorithm = algorithm, weights = weights)
regressor.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = regressor.predict(X_test)
train_score = regressor.score(X_train, y_train)
test_score = regressor.score(X_test, y_test)
```

Comment: Which `'algorithm'` are you using in it? Have you tried changing it? Is your dataset sparse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats the nature of the KNN. The algorithmic time complexity is KNN is `O(nd)` where n is number of data points & d is the dimensionality (in your case `n = 25k, d = 10`)

KNN will consider all the data points & pick up the top `K` nearest neighbours. So if your data is large it would take more time. `K` is the hyper parameter & you can tune it using [GridSearchCV](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html) or [RandomizedSearchCV](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.RandomizedSearchCV.html)

Options you have:

1. Downscale your data  (i.e, reduce the number of data points say 25k to 15K)
2. Increasing your system memory size & processor speed OR run the KNN in cloud
3. Wait till KNN completes
4. Not to use KNN if you have latency constraint

You can also try [SVM](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html) with RBF kernel since it is a nice approximation to KNN & it will take less time

Comment: Thank you for the complete answer, it helps a lot.